# Run lib build of lib from a project with pub

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart, dart-pub

I'm actually on multiple dart projects which can share code. (based on [this exemple](https://medium.com/flutter-community/code-sharing-with-bloc-b867302c18ef))

This common code use a library named [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable)

I'm using it to generate json serialization et deserialization methods for my user model.
I can use the commande `pub run build_runner build` to start the build. This way I can generate `user_model.g.dart` (which contains generated serialization and deserialization methods) from [`user_model.dart`](https://github.com/axellebot/Social-CV-Client-common/blob/master/lib/src/models/user_model.dart)

Back to my project I'm adding my shared code as a dependency.

I'd like to use my `user_model.dart` but there is an error saying that `user_model.g.dart` doesn't exist. Indeed I haven't launch the build to generate this file.

I'm trying to find a way to launch this generation of code needed by my library but this must be done from my project.

I think I need to add a build file in my lib but I can't find how to do it :/

Schema :
Project X --using--> Lib Sharing Code --using--> json_serialization

Comment: You need to run `pub run build_runner build` in the project that uses `json_serializable` not in the project that uses your shared project that uses `json_serializable`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It can be a solution but I'm not commiting generated files on the git repository. Maybe I have to ... but I was thinking about building them from the Project ... Is it the wrong way to do a library ? 
Do I have to generate file every time I'm releasing my library ? 

Comment: "I'm not commiting generated files on the git repository." That doesn't fly. Just commit it and be good. `build_runner` doesn't generate code in dependencies only in the project where it's run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit generated code.

`build_runner` can only generate code in the project it is run in, not in dependencies.

Comment: So when peoples use lib like `json_serializable` to creat a library they mainly add the generated code to git repository ? &amp;#129300;

Seems to be best practices ?

Comment: Yes. It's just to automate writing the boilerplate code.